# Is it possible to save Excel .xlsm file?

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I'm making a Python program that opens, edits, and saves xlsm Excel files with VBA. However, in this line `wb.save(filename = 'b.xlsm')`, the following error is occurring: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 19 and b, line 20, column 12.

I must edit and save the xlsm file.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'a.xlsm', keep_vba = True)
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(1,1).value = 'test'
print(ws.cell(1,1).value)

wb.save(filename = 'b.xlsm')
```

Comment: Your code works for me, can you open a.xlsm in excel ?

Comment: does the file contains form objects?

Comment: Yes, a.xlsm contains form objects.

Comment: openpyxl does not works with form objects, with [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html) you can do that, but excel must be installed and works on Windows and macOS

Comment: Please include the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna guess something is broken in another part of your code, as this aren't 20 lines and the code on itself runs just fine on my machine :) Based on the error code, you are just missing a bracket somewhere

Comment: This is my entire code. I make this sample code and then I will make another code.